# Find incentre of a complex triangle?

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry, complex-numbers, triangles

> If end points of diagonal AC of a square ABCD are A(z) and C(w) on a argand plane , then what is the incentre of triangle ABC  .

---

My try

let A be on y axis , C be on x axis and B is origin .

Let $A=ia$ then $w=a$

and argument of incentre would be $\pi /4$

but now how to proceed .

Answer is given as $\frac {z+w}{2}+i\frac{z-w}{2}(\sqrt 2 -1)$

Comment: You need the incenter in terms of w and z?

Comment: Yes I nedd that in terms of w and z @Sawarnik

Comment: Well use rotation then, rotate the w-z vector by $\frac{\pi}8$ and scale it by an appropriate ratio :)

Comment: @Sawarnik whats the use of rotating hypotenuse

Comment: Rotation and scaling will transfor the w-z vector to w-z' vector where z' is the incenter.

Comment: @Sawarnik whats the reason behing this

Comment: Do the geometry, find the angle by which to shift the side to an angle bisector, and find the ratio using trig, and you'll see it.

Comment: @Sawarnik sorry I could not understand what tou are trying to understanding .

Comment: You can't tell the incentre in terms of $\omega$ and $z$ without specifying the coordinates.

Comment: @A---B but the incentre is also in terms of w and z

Answer (score 1):

HINT: So far, so good.
You may find the center$(O_x,O_y)$ by using: $$O_x=\frac{aA_x+bB_x+cC_x}{a+b+c}$$ $$O_y=\frac{aA_y+bB_y+cC_y}{a+b+c}$$

You already have Coodinates of A,B and C. You know the length of a,b,c.
Although. My answer doesn't seem to provide you in terms of $w,z$ immediately. You have to convert it.

Suggestions are welcomes in improvement.

Comment: I could not understand how to convert it in w and z terms